# spark application does not create log file

Tags: apache-spark

I'm running my spark application.I want record some statement with log4j, and save as file in a linux directory.
  When I run the spark job , it gets launched and finished successfully.but I dont see job.log created.
  below is my config.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, E
log4j.appender.E=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.E.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.E.File=${SPARK_HOME}/statistic_log/job.log
log4j.appender.E.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.E.layout.ConversionPattern=%-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  [%r] - [%p]  %m%n
log4j.appender.E.Append=true
log4j.appender.E.Threshold=INFO
```

I am sure there is no problem with permission.Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When submit my spark app, should list my `log4j.properties` to the `--conf` argument.Otherwise spark will use `${SPARK_HOME}/conf/log4j.properties` as default.

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/storage/statistical_data/resources/log4j.properties"
```

Answer (score 0):

your log file is created at worker node, if you didn't log anything in the driver, the job.log will not exists on the driver.

Find your log on the workers.